# Plotting a brownian motion chart

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a revenue path based on Brownian Motion walks in R, but the last code doesn't work. Can you please help figure out what is wrong?

The message I got was:

> error: 'x' and 'y' must have same number of rows

```
R0 <- 13        #initial revenue
T <- 10         #maturity in years 
n <- 100000     #number of sample paths
n_step <- 10    #Time steps until T=10 years
dt <- T/n_step  #length of one time step
R <- matrix(0,nrow=n_step,ncol=n)
Rand <- matrix(rnorm(n_step*n), n_step, n)

for (j in 1:n){
  R[1,j]<- R0
  for (i in 2:n_step){
    R[i,j] <- R[i-1,j]*exp((mu[i]-(sig[i]^2)/2)*dt+sig[i]*sqrt(dt)*Rand[i,j])
    if(R[i,j]<0){
      R[i,j] <- 0
    }
  }
}

bm <- apply(R, 1, cumsum)
matplot(seq(0, T, length.out=n_step+1), bm, type='l', col=rainbow(n), 
        xlab='Time', ylab='Value',          
        main='Sample paths of standard Brownian motion')
```

Comment: It simply warns you about : `length(bm)` is not equal to `length(seq(0, T, length.out=n_step+1))` which is equal to 10. How about running this instead? `matplot( bm, type='l', col=rainbow(n), xlab='Time', ylab='Value',main='Sample paths of standard Brownian motion'))`